# Object Recognition with Minoru

Tags: ros, pcl, object-recognition, 3d-object-recognition, rospackage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm using a Minoru 3D webcam for object recognition. Will any ROS packages help in object detection and recognition using point clouds published from Minoru? All the information I get from the forum is about Kinect. I'm not sure if those methods work with Minoru?

If, instead of ROS, I were to use stand alone PCL, how will I be able to use point clouds published in ROS to use in standalone PCL.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12820/object-recognition-with-minoru/) by [PriyankaP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1050/priyankap/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2012-01-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's nothing special about the Kinect that keeps those techniques from working on a Minoru. (Although the Kinect will likely result in better data.)

If you want to communicate between ROS and PCL, see the `pcl_ros` package; it provides several helpful wrapper functions.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2012-06-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0